# Compounds involving compounds

Tags: hyphenation

Consider the following use of a hyphen:

> There are many bear-like animals.

Now, how does the hyphenation change if "bear" is replaced by "grizzly bear"?  Which of the following would be appropriate:

> There are many grizzly bear-like animals.
>
> There are many grizzly bear -like animals.

The intended meaning is *not* "There are many grizzly (gray-haired) animals that resemble bears," but rather "there are many animals that resemble grizzly bears (*Ursus arctos*)".

Comment: Such a sentence is always rephrased. It would be either "many grizzly animals that are bear-like" or "many animals that are like the grizzly bear".

Comment: Some authorities recommend using an en-dash rather than a hyphen in this case. So "grizzly bear–like animals" rather than "grizzly bear-like animals". And the other meaning could be expressed with  a comma: "grizzly, bear-like animals".

Comment: Some authorities seem never to use pens.

Comment: @Kris I don't think that's true.  What if someone *said* a sentence like this and you had to write it down?

Comment: @snailboat That's the situation that tests your understanding of the dictation-taking principles: It is one of the situations where you should *never* use your judgment but insist on the speaker to clarify. "If in doubt, ask; do not guess." -- here's the best example case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no convention that uses a gap followed by a hyphen in a compound.

The construction 'grizzly bear-like animals' would be read as using two premodifiers, 'grizzly' and 'bear-like', as you fear.

One is left with the construction using a single compound premodifier needing two hyphens:

> There are many grizzly-bear-like animals.

[Mark Nichol](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/5-examples-of-the-need-for-multiple-hyphenation/) explains about the need to tack together the cohesive parts of some premodifiers; though he doesn't give an exactly similar example, just as bear-like needs the tacking together* (even if used as a postmodifier), so do grizzly-bear-like and sabre-toothed-tiger-like.

I'll add a (not very elegant, I admit) variant of a classic example of the need for disambiguation where the premodifiers may possibly be grouped in ways with different meanings:

She gave him one of those sweet shop-girl smiles.

She gave him one of those sweet-shop-girl smiles.

*bearlike is given as a solid compound in most dictionaries, but this doesn't seem to be the favoured web spelling. In any case, I'd certainly opt for grizzly-bear-like over grizzly-bearlike or grizzlybearlike.

Comment: I encounter this problem continually with dates when writing history essays. 'A seventeenth-century viewpoint', is written hyphenated thus. But if I want to say 'A seventeenth-century-determined religious structure' presumably you are saying that that requires two hyphens. How about if I say  'a sixteenth-century, religiously-polarised, argument', can I get away with it in this way, or do I need three hyphens?

Comment: @WS2 *seventeeth century* doesn't need a hyphen, if it matters at all. A minimalist 'a sixteenth century religiously polarized argument' is nice to read and unambiguous, so a better example may be needed :)

Comment: @Kris. All of these terms must be hyphenated if they are pre-modifier compounds. That is what the OP and Edwin Ashworth's reply are all about.

Comment: @WS2 I disagree that EA's answer says **anything like** 'all of these terms must be hyphenated ...'. I went to the trouble of explaining that bear-like (it is a typical 'X-like' hyphenated compound adjective) takes a hyphen, and that {grizzly bear-like} is correctly read as {grizzly and bear-like}, and that {grizzly-bear-like} is another example of 'X-like', where X, which is this time an open compound, now needs hyphenating to show cohesion and avoid ambiguity. 'A sixteenth century religiously polarised ...' contains two serial open compound adjectivals, and is unambiguous as Kris says.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. So, in simple-man's language, am I therefore right in thinking that a compound pre-modifier does not need to be hyphenated, provided the meaning is unambiguous? Who is the body that determines things like this? Forgive me, please, for assuming that a central editorial policy of this site was that there is no such thing as an Academie Anglaise!

Comment: @WS2 Exactly - you can find 'authorities' listing different 'rules'. So in saying 'all of these terms must be ...' you're either quoting or setting yourself up as one of these dictatorships. All agree though that disambiguation is essential - even if reformulation is necessary. [Yahoo! answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080529053928AAMFL8O) has a few sensible-looking 'rules' / recommendations from various people / bodies (though contributors there mix up 'compounds' and 'phrases'). However, the 'rules' prove to be inconsistent, & dependent on eg local spelling conventions.

Comment: ... Here is the again differing recommendation from the Penguin Writer's Manual: Adjectives ending in -like may be written with or without a hyphen (catlike; hair-like) although common compound adjectives ending in -like are usually written without a hyphen (childlike; lifelike)... bell-like only, but owllike _or_ owl-like ...>> The next question is 'which adjectives ending in -like are to be regarded as 'common' in the implementation of this rule-of-thumb? Bears being more common in the US ...

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Sounds to me as though it is better to err on the side of hyphenation. I can't see how one can be criticised for that.

Comment: @WS2 Unless you want a degree from [North Carolina State University](http://www.ncsu.edu/ncsu/grammar/Hyphen3.html) : _The hyphen is a tool good writers use to speed the reader on his way. But good writers are also efficient. They don’t use extra punctuation when it’s not needed. Thus, the rule is to use hyphens only when they are needed for clarity._

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I'm not certain that message has got to every humanities department in Britain!

Comment: Use uses an en-dash with open compounds, not a hyphen.