# Hyphenation of the suffix "like"

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation, writing-style, compound-adjectives

I am having trouble understanding the following:

"the achievable rate of the optimal AF scheme performs close to the **cut-set like bound** obtained in this paper"

I think that the word "like" (above) is intended to be used as a suffix to express the fact that the bound is "cut-set"-like.

My question is what to do in such a case to show the connection between the words. Is it 
(a) "cut set-like"
(b) "cut-set-like"
(c) "cut set(en dash)like"
(d) something else

Please help me.

Comment: Is it possible to choose an example which we would all understand?

Comment: @WS2 One *can* understand the example sentence, though the subject may be unfamiliar.

Comment: I am sure this has been dealt with already on this site. Have you checked previous posts?

Comment: Though *cut-set-like*, *cut set-like*, *cut-set like*, *cut set like* are all acceptable, ***cut-set like*** is the best option in the given context. The *like* may not necessarily be hyphenated, but in the given context, *cut* and *set* need to be one hyphenated compound.

Comment: If "cut-set" is to remain hyphenated, then one could interpret the noun to be "like bound", which I don't think is the intended meaning here. In addition, I don't (em dash) unfortunately for me (em dash) get easy examples in my line of work, which is why I am grateful that this site exists!

Comment: I cannot find any examples of a suffix being joined to a hyphenated compound in the adjectival sense. Thus, I am perplexed by this case and feel that perhaps I am misinterpreting it or something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compounds involving compounds](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134891/compounds-involving-compounds)

Comment: To avoid ambiguity as much as possible, cutsetlike or cut-set-like are preferable (though rephrasing would probably be best). To avoid reading difficulty, I'd opt for the doubly-hyphenated form.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking one should use a hyphenation when two or more words form a single adjective.  One simple example might be "a four-lane highway."  The highway is not a four and a lane but a four-lane.  The hyphen ensures that no confusion ensues.  Another example might be a 24-year-old girl.  The girl is not 24, year, and old but rather a 24-year-old.

In your example of "cut-set like bound" the phrase would indicate that the bound is both like and cut-set.  Although I do not understand exactly what the phrase means, I consider it unlikely that the bound is like.  Accordingly, I recommend "the cut-set-like bound" as the optimum phrase.