# "easy to use" versus "easy-to-use"

Tags: hyphenation

My belief is that the following two phrases are correct:

A: "The app is easy to use."
B: "It is an easy-to-use app."

And that the following is not technically correct:

C: "It is an easy to use app."

If anyone can point out that C is correct versus B, would you mind pointing to an English language "rule" that shows why? My general rule-of-thumb is that if a section of the compound adjective cannot exist on its' own merit, hyphenate.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compounds involving compounds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134891/compounds-involving-compounds) Additionally, this one is in at least one online dictionary (hyphenated in a prenominal example), though even in prenominal examples hyphens are often dropped when negligible difficulty in parsing ensues.

Comment: (C) is just a different way to punctuate (B); there's no punctuation in speech, so hyphens don't matter. If you're writing, however, the rule is _an eleven-year-old boy_ versus _a boy eleven years old_. Note that plurals don't survive pre-posing, and that hyphens indicate the single-word status of a preposed modifier

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Prepositive modifiers don't like to have postpositive dependents.   The more common pattern employs prepositive dependents:

> It is a very easy app.

The "very" is a prepositive modifier of "easy", and the phrase "very easy" is prepositive to the "app" that it modifies.

Another common pattern has postpositive dependents for a postpositive modifier:

> The app is easy to use.

When a prepositive modifier has a postpositive dependent, there is a conflict.   The prepositive modifier is expected to modify the next word, but there's a postpositive dependent competing for that same word position.

The way to solve the word placement competition is to treat the phrase "easy to use" as a single word.   The hyphens join the more tightly bound phrase.  Inside the hyphenated phrase, the expectation of the postpostive dependent position of "to use" is fulfilled.   As a result, the "I'm modifying the very next word" expectation of the prepositive "easy-to-use" is easy to fulfill.

> This is an easy-to-use app.

Postpositive modification inside the hyphenation, prepositive modification outside.   The shift between right-to-left parsing and left-to-right parsing is clearly marked.

---

Edit:

There is another word ordering that might be worth comparative consideration:

> This is an easy app to use.

In this example, "to use" is definitely a postpositive dependent, but the word from which it depends is ambiguous.   In this position, "to use" could modify either "app" or "easy".

This ambiguity does not result in any word-ordering conflicts.     Regardless of whether "to use" depends from "easy" or from "app", it is in its expected postpositive position.   The boundary between left-to-right and right-to-left parsing does not need to be marked.

Comment: What about in the sentence, "This app is a great combination of powerful and easy-to-use"? Hyphens would seem better here.

Comment: Supporting references?

Answer (score 5):

You can check [here](http://www.thewriter.com/what-we-think/style-guide/to-hyphenate-or-not-to-hyphenate/):

> A compound adjective usually gets a hyphen when it comes before a noun, like in ‘a well-honed piece of writing’.
>
> But if the first word ends in ‘ly’, like in ‘a specially designed workshop’, you don’t need a hyphen.
>
> **When it comes after the noun, the compound adjective usually doesn’t get a hyphen. So we say an easy-to-remember number, but the number is easy to remember. Same goes for up to date – if it’s before a noun it needs a hyphen. A document is up to date but it’s an up-to-date document.**

So you are right in saying that statement B is correct and C is incorrect. Since the noun 'app' is preceded by the compound adjective, it is to be hyphenated as done in statement B.