# Do we need to hyphenate the compund noun if it is given as an object complement?

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives, complements

I have a question about hyphenating compound nouns when they function as object complements. For instance, should **entertainment oriented** be hyphenated in below sentence?

> Much of the radio programming was entertainment oriented.

Likewise, **well-acknowledged**

> This issue is well acknowledged.

Comment: 'Well [-] acknowledged' is a compound adjective, and this has been answered before, several times, Mohamed. // Does this answer your question? ["easy to use" versus "easy-to-use"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293323/easy-to-use-versus-easy-to-use) There are others. Compound adjectives placed before the noun are usually hyphenated; if used predicatively, they're usually not.

Answer (score 1):

A common bit of style guidance is to hyphenate them when they are used attributively. Thus *entertainment-oriented programming* but *programming that’s entertainment oriented*.

Comment: I agree, but can you document the advice? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: Please check for likely duplicate questions / answers before answering.

Comment: There's no reason not to hyphenate the predicative "entertainment-oriented". It's just as much a compound adjective there as it is when it's in attributive position.

Comment: I agree, @BillJ, that it’s compound in either position. But such usage authorities as the *Chicago Handbook of Style* do make the distinction. The motivation is to avoid the greater risk of ambiguity in phrases like *We observed a man-eating shark*, which might describe an experience during a scuba dive, versus *We observed a man eating shark*, which would be recounting more often an evening at a seafood restaurant. This ambiguity is not an issue when the compound modifier is used predicatively: *The shark we observed was man eating.”

Comment: I don't see any potential ambiguity. For the meaning _a man who was eating shark_ a hyphen is absent, not to avoid ambiguity, but because it is not grammatically required. Note that no hyphen means no compound.

Comment: Yes, but for the other meaning, omitting the hyphen does create ambiguity in the attributive use, whereas there’s no such ambiguity in the predicative, and that’s why *Chicago* distinguishes between the two positions. Anyway, if you disagree, you’re free to take it up with them. All I have been doing is reporting “a common bit of style guidance.”