# Compound Modifiers: When to hyphenate?

Tags: hyphenation

I'm writing about a new technology "Input Optimised Filtering" (not the actual name but a good example). I'm wondering whether this can/needs to be hyphenated (Input-Optimised Filtering), or not.

Comment: Relevant: [How to hyphenate a phrasal adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/430949/how-to-hyphenate-a-phrasal-adjective-pci-compliant?rq=1)

Comment: Also: [How to hyphenate an open form compound word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51665/how-do-i-hyphenate-an-open-form-compound-word-with-another-that-should-be-hyphen?rq=1)

Comment: Preliminary point: if indeed "input+optimised is a compound word, then it must be written as a single word, in this case hyphenated. There are a few syntactic tests that can be performed to check for compoundhood. One test is: can the component parts enter separately into relations of coordination? i.e. can input + optimised filtering become a coordination as in [input- and optimised-] filtering. Another is: can the individual components be modified as in, for example "input-[xyz optimised filtering]". If the answer to either one of those tests is no, then it's probably a compound.

Comment: Note also that if it is written as two separate words it is an adjective (or noun) phrase i.e. a syntactic construction consisting of modifier+head. By contrast, if two bases combine to form a single word, then it is a compound.