# Should there be hyphenation in words that specify a process or concept or something similar to these?

Tags: hyphenation

There are sentences wherein processes, concepts etc. are hyphenated. 
For eg., progress-enhancement process, authentic-leadership approach etc.
I know there is no need of hyphenation in these cases, but what is the rationale behind  placing hyphens for such words? Is it correct?

Comment: It depends entirely on the style you follow. Incidentally, where you put the hyphen *changes* the meaning of the phrase. (Which is the point of the hyphen, especially if there is ambiguity.) For instance, I know what an *authentic leadership-approach* is (a leadership approach that's authentic), which is what I'd assume is the meaning of the three words without a hyphen. However, I'm not sure what  an *authentic-leadership approach* is. An approach for (or of?) authentic leaders as opposed to fake leaders? I've never heard of such a thing before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compounds involving compounds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134891/compounds-involving-compounds) (and the linked duplicates there). The question is broader than your title suggests; << _three hundred year old trees_ >> and << _one of those sweet shop girl smiles_ >> are strings badly in need of hyphenation.