# Hyphen in consecutive adjectives

Tags: hyphenation

Is the hyphen necessary in cases such as:
lexical-functional grammar
(lexical functional grammar)??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compounds involving compounds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134891/compounds-involving-compounds) [sweet-shop girl vs sweet shop girl] And/or this? [Is it correct to hyphenate with compound premodifiers? If so, where is the hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/is-it-correct-to-hyphenate-with-compound-premodifiers-if-so-where-is-the-hyphe) [file-system related v file system-related, etc]

Comment: Generally, there are very few adj+adj compound adjectives. Two decent examples I found are "syntactic-semantic investigation" and "Swedish-Irish trade". I'd include your example too: Lexical-Functional grammar".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean.

lexical-functional grammar - a **grammar** that has lexical functionality

lexical functional grammar - a **functional grammar** that is also lexical

Note: See important comments below by @FumbleFingers

Comment: So according to you, [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_functional_grammar) ISN'T about the same thing as [this oxfordhandbooks paper.](https://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199544004.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199544004-e-017) Despite the fact that they ***both*** explicitly point out that the grammar they're talking about is also known by its abbreviation LFG. I think you're trying to rationalise a distinction that doesn't exist and/or is meaningless anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - But I am answering a different question, i.e. - the one I perceived the questioner  to be asking. Because the OP said "such as", I assumed that it was the general principle that was being asked about, not a specific case. There is a distinction between a red brick wall and a red-brick wall. The first may be a wall that has been painted red. The second is a wall made from red bricks.

Comment: Ah, i see what you mean. I'll remove my downvote, which in the circumstances now seems unreasonable. But I do think it's worth explicitly pointing out that your "rules of deconstruction" aren't *always* applicable / meaningful. As illustrated by the fact that it was so easy for me to find a clear-cut case of two "authoritative" sources using different hyphenation for what's unquestionably the same referent. And maybe that caveat would be better in your answer text rather than down here in potentially ephemeral comments.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'll edit my answer to reference your comments. When I have time, I'll amend my answer properly.